# What should I be "informed" about to cast votes?

Tags: discussion

Apparently, I need to be "informed" to cast a vote. Or *should* be

> The question is, is it informed, and that's an empirical question. But
> before I lay bare your "expertise", I want you to understand the
> system: your downvote removes a couple of points, but my upvote adds
> ten points. Thus, a contributor is 8 points ahead anytime we disagree
> in such a fashion. Now, let's respond to your comment about "original
> research"

What am I meant to be informed about? That I am down-voting someone who is a doctor of philosophy? If that is the case, they should be more aware of when they are doing "original research", not less.

IIRC, the particular issue was whether only "tokens" can be performative. This does not seem like a trivial claim to me (CF my down-voted answer about unusual wedding vows: say whatever you want). Where does it appear? If it appears nowhere, then the question should certainly be on a negative score.

Notwithstanding how it seems to have confused other voters into thinking it's *not* original research.

---

More generally, is this site for answering questions to the best of our ability, or is it a social networking site? Yes, that will involve google. No, that doesn't mean we use google to bullshit away any question or answer we want to.

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/87117/56815

The difference is everything...